# Is there vegan glue that works well on fabric?

Tags: veganism, fabric

I want to buy fabric glue but I suspect that the kinds you normally find are not vegan. Are there a vegan fabric glues, or alternative adhesives that would work for fabric?

Comment: Weldbond makes a vegan all-purpose glue. I have heard that it is good for fabrics.

Comment: Are you glueing fabric to fabric, or fabric to something else?

Comment: Fabric to fabric

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention 2 links I found on google and their caption and info here as an answer to your question.

**But We are not sure whether the product is available in your country or not.**

It depends on the manufacturer.

1. [Elmer's](http://www.elmers.com/about/faqs/general)

> Elmer's does not make glue from horses or use animals or animal parts. Our products are made from synthetic materials and are not derived from processing horses, cows or any other animals.

2. [weldbond](http://weldbond.com/)

> Weldbond® is a universal adhesive that bonds most anything! It is non-toxic, nonflammable, free of fumes, has low VOCs, is created without animal by-products and environmentally friendly!

Comment: are these suitable for fabric?

Comment: A search on elmer's shows that both are available
http://www.elmers.com/search-results?s=fabric%20glue

weldbond says that it support wood, tile, glass and **more**

Comment: Just because a glue will attach two fabrics together does not mean it is good as a fabric glue (which typically retains some flexibility and doesn't completely bleed through). Elmer's would be a better choice.

Comment: Nice to know that Elmer's doesn't contain animal products! I might try these both out and report back on which works better